# Lodash Grab key from a nested property

Tags: lodash

I've looked at a number of SO posts and gotten myself confused as to the `_.findKey` function of loDash.

I have working code, in that it returns the correct value, but have an unwanted side-effect that I need rid of.

Example data;

```
responderRooms = {
  MasterVal: {
    status: Value1,
    time: Value2,
    msg: Value3,
    responders: {
      4471230123456: {}
    }
  }
}
```

I know what the `4471230123456` value is and am attempting to learn the `MasterVal` key.

Typically, `_.findKey' would allow me to specify the array, path and a value to look for. For example,

```
 console.log( _.findKey(responderRooms, 'time', 'Value2') // Returns MasterVal
```

However when the value to be matched is part of nested array, I'm trying:

```
 var responderIndex = _.findKey(responderRooms, function(o) {
        return o.responders.tel = 4471230123456;
    });
```

Which does return the correct key, but adds a further 'tel = NewSentTo' to the ResponderVal array. Resulting in:

```
responderRooms = {
  MasterVal: {
    status: Value1,
    time: Value2,
    msg: Value3,
    responders: {
      4471230123456: {},
      tel: 4471230123456 // << This shouldn't be here!
    }
  }
}
```

How can I find the Masterkey value, using the key of a nested object as criteria, without adding an additional property?

`responders` is created with:

```
 objPath = MasterVal + '.responders.' + data.tel
    _.set(responderRooms, objPath, {
            name: data.name,
            type: data.type,
            msgStatus: data.msgStatus,
            location: data.location,
            jobStatus: data.jobStatus
    });
```

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Replace `o.responders.tel = 4471230123456` (assign to `tel`) with `o.responders.tel === 4471230123456` (compare to `tel`).

Comment: In addition, there's a problem with your data structure - arrays don't work like this: `responders: [ 4471230123456: { type: rVal1, name: rVal2, location: rVal3  }`.

Comment: Thanks, but === instead of = is returning undefined, although your comment makes perfect sense... Still stuck

Comment: Assignment returns the assigned property, which is casted to `true`, comparison means `false` to `find`. You didn't actually find the property.

Comment: Thanks @OriDrori, I appreciate your help. I've updated the question with the structure of the data. I don't understand why I get the correct variable when using assign to, rather than compare to. Is it easier just to remove the superfluous value afterwards?

Comment: Because assignment of a truthy value always returns `true`, and `MasterVal` is the first and only key, so find will return it, and other keys, and try to find them. `responders` is supposed to be an object or an array?

Comment: I think _set is creating an array rather than an object elsewhere in my code... Have updated my code

Comment: I've updated `responders` to be an object, and added a solution. See if it works for you.

Comment: What's the `objPath` you are using?

Comment: `objPath = MasterVal + '.responders.' + data.tel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `_.has()` to check if the key exists in the `responders` object:

```js
const responderRooms = {
  DemoKey1: {},
  DemoKey2: {},
  MasterVal: {
    status: 1,
    time: 2,
    msg: 3,
    responders: {
      4471230123456: {}
    }
  }
}

const responderKey = _.findKey(responderRooms, o => 
  _.has(o.responders, 4471230123456)
)

console.log(responderKey)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I think part of the problem lie in how the responders object (array) is created. I'm using _.set which the docs suggest: Arrays are created for missing index properties while objects are created for all other missing properties

Comment: And you are using a numeric value. Try to convert it to an actual string `447-1230123456 ` for example.

Comment: It's being passed as a string. I've changed to _.setWith and set the moderniser as `object` following the example in the doc. The text is 'object' but it is annotated like an array: `responders: [ '447123012345': [Object] ]`

Comment: Arrays are objects in JS, so you're adding properties to the array.